# How to extract multiple digits from one row using Regex in R

Tags: r, regex, string, extract

I need to extract all the numbers of a row using str_extract and Regex (if possible) in R language. I have a row from a dataframe looking like this:

```
    
 8.75 9.25 9.00 9.00 8.75 9.25 9.25 9.04
```

I would like to extract one number at a time.

Thank you in advance for your help :)

I have tried this code:

```
A.uno = str_extract(DF_98[26,], ".\\S+")

A.dos = str_extract(DF_98[26,], ".\\D+.\\D+.\\S+")
```

where DF_98[26,] is the row above described.

The first line of the code extracted the first number of the row.

But I dont know how to extract separately the rest of the numbers. The second line is a poor try but it didnt work.

Comment: One of your problems is that you do not yet understand that these cannot be numbers in R. R only represents decimal points with a period ".".They might be in a file and if so you need to learn how to read numeric data with European decimal points. See ?read.table. If you have them in an R data object then `as.numeric(gsub(",", ".", obj))`

Comment: `str_extract` extracts the first match. `str_extract_all` extracts all matches. But it's not clear what your input is... you call it "row" not "string" or "character"? What's the class of `DF_98`? And is there any reason you're not using `read.table` as IRTFM suggests? Do you *need* to use regex? `read.table` could read this all perfectly.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. DF_98 is a dataframe created from the raw text of a pdf, it has some columns and several rows. I just wanted to extract the digits separately from one of the rows. For example, I would like to extract only 9.04, not all the numbers. I am using regex because I have to extract this data from other 1000 pdfs.

Answer (score 0):

I think this creates a character value like what you appear to have:

```
val <-"8,75 9,25 9,00 9,00 8,75 9,25 9,25 9,04" # comma as decimal separators
obj <- scan(text=val, what="" ) #read using whitespace as separator
#Read 8 items
as.numeric( gsub(",", ".", obj) ) # first change commas to period then coerce
#[1] 8.75 9.25 9.00 9.00 8.75 9.25 9.25 9.04
```

Comment: No need for the `as.numeric` conversion after `scan` as you can set the decimal point - `scan(text=val, dec=",", what=numeric())`

Comment: Guess I forgot ro read the manual/

Comment: IFTRTFM doesn't have the same ring to it.

Comment: `sub(“U”, “usually”,  "IURTFM”)`